# wordCount frequency returns repeated Set in java

Tags: java, frequency, word-count

I have a method which returns single word as a String. I need to count all those words returned by the method which reads chunk of text. Problem is I am getting the count right but output is wrong. It's repeating. Not quite sure where is things going wrong?

```
private int totalWords    = 0;
private static Map<String, Integer> wordFrequency = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


public static void findResult(CharacterReader characterReader)
{
    boolean x = true;
    CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.allocate(100);
    String str = "";
    try
    {

        while(x)
        {
        char cha = characterReader.getNextChar();
        Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<Character>();
            charSet.add(',');
            charSet.add('.');
            charSet.add(';');
            charSet.add(':');
            charSet.add('\'');
            charSet.add('~');
            charSet.add('?');
            charSet.add('!');
            charSet.add('%');


            while(cha != ' ' && !charSet.contains(cha))
            {
                buffer.put(cha);
                cha = characterReader.getNextChar();
            }
            buffer.flip();
            str = buffer.toString();
            buffer.clear();



            countWords(str);

            System.out.println(wordFrequency);

        }
    }catch(EOFException e)

    {
        x = false;
    }


private static void countWords(String word)
        {

                if (wordFrequency.containsKey(word))
                {
                    Integer count = wordFrequency.get(word);
                    count++;
                    wordFrequency.put(word, count);
                    } else {
                    wordFrequency.put(word, 1);
                }
        }

public static void main (String args[])
{
    CharacterReader cr = new SimpleCharacterReader();
    findResult(cr);
}
```

Comment: Output:

[ 
It=1}
{ 
It=1, was=1}
{ 
It=1, the=1, was=1}
{ 
It=1, best=1, the=1, was=1]

Comment: I don't see any method above which returns a String. Please clarify.

Comment: This is a well documented topic on SO, please use the search facility

Comment: I have been looking at lots of posts from SO, but didn't get anything relate to the repeated problem I am afraid.

Comment: @shaz The code that you posted above doesn't have any problems with it, without more context we can't really help.

Comment: I agree. It's likely how you're using the code, but this question is woefully lacking in information that would allow us to be able to help you.

Comment: you should list the whole code that can we understand it

Comment: put charSet.add(' '); to your code and change  while(!CharSet.contains(cha))

Comment: to your question "Another problem is it counts blank, for example {=16, to=2}." You also count empty Strings str=='' !! change          if (str != ''){countWords(str);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in where you've placed your System.out.println. You've got it ***inside*** of the loop!

```
    while(x) {
        // .....

        countWords(str);

        System.out.println(wordFrequency);
    }
```

Solution: do it *after* the loop.

```
    while(x) {
        // .....

        countWords(str);

    }
    System.out.println(wordFrequency);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was the problem. Another problem is it counts blank, for example {=16, to=2}. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: @shaz: test the trimmed String to see if it's blank before adding it to the map. Not to be harsh, but you should be able to figure this one out yourself.

Comment: nothing to be harsh about. It's absolutely fine. I have sorted the space issue out. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Move

System.out.println(wordFrequency);

To outside the try statement. You are printing the whole set after each word.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving 
System.out.println(wordFrequency);
out of the while loop braces...

Comment: That is in short the same answer as @Hovercraft Full Of Eels